# : command not foundar in my bash script

Tags: bash

If I run this

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
hadoop fs -ls
```

clear is not executed. Instead I get

```
: command not foundar
Found 2 items
list of items
```

If I add ";" after clear it gets executed, but I still get

```
: command not found
Found 2 items
list of items
```

Why is that?

Comment: Is that really `command not found` as in the title, or is it `command not foundar` as in the quoted output.  The fact that `clear` ends in `ar` is suspicious.

Comment: @Jim It's command not foundar. Why is that suspicious?

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: @Avihoo sh scr.sh

Comment: I suspect that is your problem.. you run it through `sh` shell, but your shebang line declares `bash`. Try run: `bash scr.sh`

Comment: @Avihoo get **: command not foundar** without a ";" and **: command not found** with ";" too

Comment: Do you run this script under Linux or Windows?

Comment: @Avi I am sitting on a windows machine connected to a linux server through putty =P So I am running it on linux, I guess. I checked the link you provided and you were right. The problem is the same.

Comment: So you need to use `dos2unix scr.sh` to remove all the line ends that fits to windows but not to linux.

Comment: @Avi I thought so too) But `dos2unix scr.sh
bash: dos2unix: command not found`

Comment: @EugeneCuz Just because you do not *have* that command doesn't mean you don' t need to do what it does. See the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for more suggestions.

Comment: @che I solved my problem this way `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' winfile.sh > unixfile.sh`

Comment: When weird stuff like this happens, my goto is `xxd scr.sh` to check if there's something unusual going on